# Best choice for reflow performances on toggle hide widgets

Tags: javascript, html, performance, layout, reflow

I got a question about **reflow performances.**

Considering this HTML :

```
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>

    all HTML soup here
    ...

    <div class="widget-one" id="widget-one">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="widget-two" id="widget-two">
        ...
    </div>

    <div class="widget-three" id="widget-three">
        ...
    </div>

    <nav>
        <a class="widget-one-anchor" href="#widget-one">widget one</a>
        <a class="widget-two-anchor" href="#widget-two">widget two</a>
        <a class="widget-three-anchor" href="#widget-three">widget three</a>
    </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

An XHR request is made every 5 minutes and show me up **which 'widget + anchor' I have to display or hide.**

For example if I have to hide the 'widget-two', i will also have to hide the 'widget-two-anchor'.
And this for each widget + associate anchor or any other associate DOM element.

**I currently have two choice to accomplish that (I'll appreciate if you have a better solution).**

1. **With JavaScript:** for each 'widget': hide or display it and hide or display the associates-widget DOM elements (in this case,
   the anchor).
2. **With JavaScript and CSS:**  Add a class on `<body>` element, for example **'hide-widget-two'** that hide the widget and all the
       associates-widget DOM elements (in this case, the anchor) by CSS
       dependence.

For example :

```
.hide-widget-two .widget-two,
.hide-widget-two .widget-two-anchor {
    display:none;
}
```

I choose the second one, because of maintainability: it's easier to hide or show many element with CSS rather than with JavaScript. If tomorrow I have to add another associate-widget DOM element I will just have to update my CSS file.

Because i saw on this article [Minimizing browser reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) that changing one level in the DOM tree can cause changes at every level of the tree, **so which choice is better ?**

**Toggle classes on body and may cause a reflow on the whole page ?
Or toggle style display on every items and cause a reflow for each DOM tree childrens of the item ?**

Answer (score 3):

Test it. This is the only valid response to any practical performance question. Your answer depends on many things and the only way to really know what is better for you is to run each of these commands in your actual page and inspect what is going on in the dev tools timeline. This really depends on the structure of your page and the individual elements you are showing and hiding.

Note also that descendant selectors that your class-name-on-the-body example uses are quite slow to match so this is another confounding factor. Create a small test where you alternately run each effect 5-10 times a second and look at the times for paint, layout, etc. Note this will be different on different browsers as well. Check out [this](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/10/pinterest-paint-performance-case-study/) and [this](http://addyosmani.com/blog/performance-optimisation-with-timeline-profiles/) and [especially this](http://jakearchibald.com/2013/solving-rendering-perf-puzzles/) for solving performance issues with tools. [And this](http://aerotwist.com/blog/dont-guess-it-test-it/) is a good primer on how you should approach these problems, don't just seek performance advice, discover the optimal code for *your specific scenario*. Browsers change, performance advice changes, so don't do yourself the disservice of using half-baked advice to limit the performance of your site.

It seems you know enough of the performance essentials to know what to change, so go change stuff, test it, and get answers to your question that no one could give but you.

Comment: That's for the outstanding resources. Not only these articles touch on invaluable skills to match the demand of today's web technologies, but thanks to you I've also discovered great new blogs to follow. Those 50 points were well deserved!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, reflow logic is totally browser dependent, although I think applying 1 class (even to the body) has to be faster, than applying 2 classes (to widget and anchor).
But you can test both approaches, and measure reflow times with the browser's development tools (ex: safari timeline), or some plugin (ex: chrome speed tracer).